# Pandas Combining Consecutive Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to combine consecutive values in pandas to create a new output dataframe and could use some help.

Input:

```
   depth   type
0   50      0
1   100     1
2   150     1
3   200     1
4   250     0
5   300     0
6   350     0
7   400     1
8   450     1
9   500     0
```

Output:

```
   start_depth   stop_depth  type
0     100          200        1
1     400          450        1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following Wen's suggestion of `agg min/max`:

```
c=(df.type != df.type.shift()).cumsum().values
ndf = df.groupby([c, 'type']).depth.agg(['min','max']).reset_index(level=1)

    type   start  end
1   0      50     50
2   1      100    200
3   0      250    350
4   1      400    450
5   0      500    500
```

to get just `type==1`, simply select

```
ndf[ndf.type==1]

    type   start end
2   1      100   200
4   1      400   450
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution , usig `agg`

```
df.loc[df.type==1,:].groupby(df.type.eq(0).cumsum()).agg({'depth':['min','max'],'type':'first'})
Out[42]: 
      type depth     
     first   min  max
type                 
1        1   100  200
4        1   400  450
```